# Can a modally opened form (i.e. form.ShowDialog method) listen for events on an underlying form/add-in that called it?

Tags: .net, winforms, outlook-addin

I'm writing an add-in for OutLook 2007 using vb.net 2010; the add-in places a new toolbar & buttons in the OutlookUI. One of these opens a form MODALLY.

However, the "ThisAddin" class which loads in Outlook has a number Outlook-sepcific variable declared "WithEvents", e.g. to watch for items added/removed from Outlook folders.

If I use form.show instead of form.showdialog, I can update the displayed form with information from events arising in the ThisAddin Class, no problem. The problem is only when I open form.ShowDialog(), where everything freezes until I close the form.

It would really help if I could BOTH get my form to respond to events, and display it modally on top of the underlying Outlook 2007 UI.

Thanks in advance to any help that any of you are able to provide.

Jim

Comment: This is by design, a dialog becomes modal by disabling the other windows in the application.  I'm guessing you are really only after the "on top" feature but can't tell.

Comment: thanks for this. is there really no way, such as using different threads ? Outlook itself still operates (e.g. incoming emails are still received with a modal dialog open). If not, I know of the TopMost form property which I could work with. What I'm really trying to do is either show the form (if it is not open) or update the form (if it is) on each Items.ItemAdd event which occurs when multiple items are moved/dropped into an Outlook folder. Thanks again.

Answer (score 1):

[This](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/da-DK/vblanguage/thread/bd490e16-f42c-45d4-aae7-a646ee804b45) article explains exactly how to Open A Modal Form/Dialog using ShowDialog on a thread separate from that on which the main app/UI is executing, and yet still respond to Events on that main App/UI thread.